# How to initialize the date value of Angular Material md-datepicker to any specified date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

In Angular Material md-datepicker, when I click on date picker it sets the system's current date as today's date. We notice that today's date is circled in the date picker's calendar. I want to know if there is a way to set any given date as today's date. Please refer this image. [md-datepicker's calender (today's date highlighted in Yellow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbeDG.png)

So, in my case, if I set today's date as 2nd April 2017, the datepicker should set this as today's date and circle this date on the calendar

Comment: You can use       <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
and in you controller 
this.myDate = new Date('2017-04-17T03:24:00');

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<md-content ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" layout-padding="" ng-cloak="" class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout-gt-xs="row">
    <div flex-gt-xs="">
      <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']).controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.myDate = new Date('2017-04-17T03:24:00');
  this.isOpen = false;
});
```

> this.myDate = new Date('2017-04-17T03:24:00');

You can set your own date here. In your case you wanted 2nd April 2017 as default date in datetime picker then you should write

> this.myDate = new Date('2017-04-01T03:24:00');

[Live Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMKNMz)

I referred Angular Material website for this

Comment: I still found this very inconvenient... What about today? new Date() remembers time details. If I construct new Date("yyyy-mm-dd") using getMonth, getDate from new Date() I'll get UTC 0 day and in america that means Yesterday, not Today.

Comment: Works if I use another date constructor:
new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate())
this gives a date in local zone